# Multiple OnBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a JS which is used as a plugin. The JS has an onbeforeunload event.

I want suggestions so that my onbeforeunload event doesn't override the existing onbeforeunload event (if any). Can I append my onbeforeunload to the existing one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You only need to take care of this if you are not using event observing but attach your `onbeforeunload` handler directly (which you should not). If so, use something like this to avoid overwriting of existing handlers.

```
(function() {
    var existingHandler = window.onbeforeunload;
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        if (existingHandler) existingHandler(event);

        // your own handler code here
    }
})();
```

Unfortunately, you can't prevent other (later) scripts to overwrite your handler. But again, this can be solved by adding an event listener instead:

```
$(window).unload(function(event) {
    // your handler code here
});
```

Comment: Is it wanted that the second part about event listener, hooks on 'unload' meanwhile in the first part we was talking about 'onbeforeunload'?

Comment: Better to move away from your first solution and simply use
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {/*event handling*/});
as many times as you want

Answer (score 18):

I felt this has not been answered completely, because no examples were shown using `addEventListener` (but The MAZZTer pointed out the `addEventListener` solution though). My solution is the same as Julian D. but without using jQuery, only native javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Before Unload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
        console.log('handler 1')
        event.preventDefault()
        event.returnValue = ''
      });

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
        console.log('handler 2')
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, both listeners will be executed. If any other `beforeunload` listeners were set, it would not override them. We would get the following output (order is not guaranteed):

```
handler 1
handler 2
```

And, importantly, if one or more of the event listener does `event.preventDefault(); event.returnValue = ''`, a prompt asking the user if he really wants to reload will occur.

This can be useful if you are editing a form and at the same time you are downloading a file via ajax and do not want to lose data on any of these action. Each of these could have a listener to prevent page reload.

```
const editingForm = function (event) {
  console.log('I am preventing losing form data')
  event.preventDefault()
  event.returnValue = ''
}

const preventDownload = function (event) {
  console.log('I am preventing a download')
  event.preventDefault()
  event.returnValue = ''
}

// Add listener when the download starts
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', preventDownload);
// Add listener when the form is being edited
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', editingForm);

// Remove listener when the download ends
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', preventDownload);
// Remove listener when the form editing ends
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', editingForm);
```

Comment: That must be marked as an answer, because it is free from external libs and global hooks

Comment: This solution works much better than assigning directly to `window.onbeforeunload`. I can add and remove as many event listeners as I need.

Comment: why are you both preventing default *and* setting `returnValue`? you only need one or the other

Comment: The answer to my question is that apparently 50% of event evergreen browsers still don't support this most obvious standard, and directly returning the string is actually the method with the highest support

Answer (score 3):

My idea:

```
var callbacks = [];
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    while (callbacks.length) {
        var cb = callbacks.shift();
        typeof(cb)==="function" && cb();
    }
}
```

and

```
callbacks.push(function() {
    console.log("callback");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you bind using jQuery, it will append the binding to the existing list, so there is no need to worry.

From the jQuery Docs [on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the same event handler can be bound to an element
>   multiple times.

```
function greet(event) { alert("Hello "+event.data.name); }
$("button").on("beforeunload", { name: "Karl" }, greet);
$("button").on("beforeunload", { name: "Addy" }, greet);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var f = window.onbeforeunload;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    f();
    /* New code or functions */
}
```

You can modify this function many times , without losing other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different javascript frameworks like jquery or you could probably add a small event add handler to do this. Like you have an object thatcontains a number of functions that you have added and then in the onbefore unload you run the added functions. So when you want to add a new function to the event you add it to your object instead.

something like this:

```
var unloadMethods = [];
function addOnBeforeUnloadEvent(newEvent) { //new Event is a function
    unloadMethods[unloadMethods.length] = newEvent;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<unloadMethods.length; i++) {
        if(typeof unloadMethods[i] === "function") {unloadMethods[i]();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those frameworks mentioned use addEventListener internally.  If you are not using a framework, use that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

For older versions of IE you should have a fallback to use attachEvent instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I liked Marius's solution, but embellished on it to cater for situations where the var f is null, and to return the first string returned by any function in the chain:

```
function eventBeforeUnload(nextFN){
    //some browsers do not support methods in eventAdd above to handle window.onbeforeunload
    //so this is a way of attaching more than one event listener by chaining the functions together 
    //The onbeforeunload expects a string as a return, and will pop its own dialog - this is browser behavior that can't
    //be overridden to prevent sites stopping you from leaving. Some browsers ignore this text and show their own message.
    var firstFN = window.onbeforeunload;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var x;
        if (firstFN) {
            //see if the first function returns something
            x = firstFN();
            //if it does, return that
            if (x) return x;
        }
        //return whatever is returned from the next function in the chain
        return nextFN();
    }
}
```

In your code where required use it as such

```
eventBeforeUnload(myFunction);
//or
eventBeforeUnload(function(){if(whatever) return 'unsaved data';);
```